# meteor - can I remove core packages?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

is it possible to remove core packages from meteor?

I want to remove Blaze and Spacebars. In this case meteor should ship my index.html as it is, with no parsing or templating on his side.

Comment: how you are using meteor in your app?

Comment: I'm using polymer and meteor together, 
what I'm trying to archieve is full reactivity from mongo to polymer.
I want meteor just to keep data in sync. I don't need Blaze (why compete with angular, polymer or many others?) 
I have accomplished writing this small package https://atmospherejs.com/purepattern/fullreact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of 2020** this is possible for nearly all packages. There are no longer hard dependencies for Blaze and you can even remove Mongo and run Meteor with an SQL database.

To test this you should check out the [various options for creating a new Meteor project](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorcreate) - They only define which packages are added initially when creating the project and you can freely add / remove even core packages.

Answer (score 0):

The meteor core packages are included by the 'meteor-platform' packaage.  You can edit your .meteor/packages file ( or use `meteor add` and `meteor remove` to remove the 'meteor-platform' package and then add back whichever meteor packages you want.

The [packages in 'meteor-platform' are listed here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor-platform/package.js) with brief explanations'.

I don't think removing Blaze and Spacebars will lead to your index.html file remaining unchanged but don't really know. You could always just move it to the 'public' folder and then it will be served at '/index.html'.

Comment: I tried to remove meteor-platform and dont add back Blaze but it is still loading.

meteor list doesnt list blaze thou, I don't know why.
If I move it to public, meteor will not load any of their meteor packages isnt it ? I want to load them but leave the html as it is

Comment: You should remove "spacebars", "templating", and "blaze".

Comment: The webapp package, which you need for basic platform functionality,  [declares dependencies](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/package.js#L17) on the Blaze, htmljs, and Spacebars packages. It does not actually use them, but they're included. I've verified this by removing the offending list items in a fork of Meteor — they're not included. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3753) about it

Comment: As a side note, it seems any parsing of html files in your application is gone when removing blaze and templating. Which makes sense, since there's necessary template parsing to generate that, but is unfortunate as there's no simple default index.html file or anything that will be served up in lieu of using those packages

Comment: FYI: The unnecessary dependencies that @Louis mentioned were removed in Meteor 1.0.4.

Comment: They're still indirect dependencies since [boilerplate-generator](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/boilerplate-generator/package.js) depends on them though